# PHP, Failed connecting to database

Tags: php

I can't connect to my databases, whenever i try it's giving me this error
[image]

I tried to connect to the default databases like mysql, and it worked fine just like the pic shows
[image]

I'm using wamp server the latest version, here's code if needed :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$my_db="mydb";

$link=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $my_db);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("there is an error");
} else {
    echo "connected to ".$my_db;
}
```

Comment: Forgive the obvious question but do you actually have a database, not table, named mydb?

Comment: Did you create a database called `mydb`?

Comment: You are forgiven @Dave :)

Comment: And The Same code used to connect properly?

Comment: Please check the correct way to check for errors when connecting to mysql [You can find the manual page here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Dave yes i have a database called mydb, and i tested with another one i just created called test, what does not make sense that the same code runs well in other laptop, RiggsFolly, yes sir, Bilel, yes the exact same code

Comment: Did you create the `mydb` on this PC or the other PC?

Comment: *On this pc i tested the code on "mydb" and "test" which both exists ==> gets an error 
*On the other pc i tested the code on "mydb" and "test" which both exists ==> works fine

Comment: Try to connect with mysql port

Comment: @Dilek how so ?

Comment: Go to console of wamp tools and see your mysql port `$port="3306";` and include in your connection. `$link=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $my_db, $port);`

Comment: @thanks i will try it out, though i just switched to xampp and everything works just fine, ig the issue was with the wamp server,

Comment: xampp uses only mariadb, so am not sure if the problem was caused by wamp itself or just cz am trying to connect to mysql

Comment: Wampserver uses the mariaDB as default ! that is why you cant connect to database directly, you needed to specify database port into your connection. you could use mariaDB without any iseue on wamserver too.

Comment: @Dilek i understand, thanks now it really makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wampserver 3.2.0 new instalation or upgrading**

**This might help others**

Probably `xamp` using `mariaDB` as default too.

`Wamp` server comes with `mariaDB` and mysql, and instaling `mariaDB` as default on 3306 port.

To make `mysql` work!

On instalation it asks to use `mariaDB` or `MySql`, mariaDB is checked as default and you cant change it, check `mysql` option and install.

when instalation done both will be runing `mariaDB` on default port and `mysql` on another port.

Right click on `wamp` icon where its runing should be on right bottom corner, goto tools and see your `mysql` runing port.

And include in your database connection same as folowng :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$port = '3308';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

`Note :` I am using pdo.

See here for more : https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/