# Codeigniter PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database

Tags: codeigniter, exception, pdo

I have tried to host a codeigniter web application which is working perfectly on online server, to my local system. but it shows some sql error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database

Comment: i have alredy confirmed the existance of database in the local server

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813485/12232340