# Access denied to my database parameters seem o

Tags: php, mysql

I use Xampp as server. I have mysql table that i visualize with bootstrap grid. As the table have more than 1000 rows, the visualization with bootstrap is slow. I'm trying to work server side but have a problem connecting to the data base with this code

```
$dbDetails = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'company');
```

It can't contact the server or connect to the database, while with this is possible. I receive the following errors: **DataTables warning: table id=memListTable - Invalid JSON response** AND **{"error":"An error occurred while connecting to the database. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"}**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "company";
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, you're trying to connect with the wrong credentials: _"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"_.

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813485/12232340

Comment: @Dlk - Not really the same issue. The OP can't connect to the database server at all, while that post talks about connecting to a specific database while it's successfully connected. The connection should still work, regardless if it's mariaDB or MySQL.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem when I downloaded Wamp server on second pc and it was MariaDB was causing the problem. when I try to connect directly from localhost/phpmyadmin it was running to MariaDB but when I was trying to connect with php it was given same error as OP having.

Comment: @Dlk - Sure, but we don't even know if the OP is running WAMP or not. Far from everyone is.

Comment: That is true we don’t know! 1.Check if you actually created a database, 2.Check if you are trying to connect to MySQL with right database name. 3.change localhost to your ip, 4. Do what said in the answer in my comment.

Comment: @Dlk Following your link i added the port number 3308 and now i can connect to the database. Now i have another problem still with json. Have to investigate. Thanks

Comment: This question was about connecting and The problem you having now is another question! Ask a new question with your json codes and with details what you want to achieve, we can’t help without seeing your codes.